# Insert function hash table C

Tags: c, insert, hashtable

I am having trouble implementing my insert function for my hash table.

So I implement some test calls where I just call the function separately. For actual use, I call the function inside a while loop. For testing purpose, I only run the loop 4 times.

I post some outputs below. The reason the table looks weird is because of my hash function. It hashes the words such that A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, and so on. The position of the letter in the word is irrelevant, since I will consider permutations of the word. Moreover, the case of the letter will be irrelevant in this problem as well, so the value of a = the value of A = 1.

And for strings, abc = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6, bc = 2 + 3 = 5, etc.

Overall, the hash function is fine. The problem is the insert function.

The first 4 words of my local dictionary are A, A's, AA's, AB's.

My expected output should be (I got the same output when I run the test calls):

```
0: 
1: [W: A, Len:1] 
2: 
3: 
...
18: 
19: 
20: [W: A's, Len:3] 
21: [W: AA's, Len:4] 
22: [W: AB's, Len:4]
```

But when I call the function inside a loop, whatever is last on the list will overwrite other entries. If I run the loop 100 times, then the last entry still replaces the previous ones (Notice how the lengths of the words are unchanged, but only the words are replaced):

```
0: 
1: [W: AB's, L:1] 
2: 
3: 
...
18: 
19: 
20: [W: AB's, Len:3] 
21: [W: AB's, Len:4] 
22: [W: AB's, Len:4]
```

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int hash(char *word)
{
   int h = 0;

   while(*word != '\0')
   {
      if(*word >='A' && *word < 'A'+26) {
         h=h+(*word -'A' + 1);
      }
      else if(*word >='a' && *word < 'a'+26) {
         h=h+(*word -'a' + 1);
      }
      //else { // special characters
      // return -1;  
      //}

      word++;
   }

   return h;
}

typedef struct Entry {
   char *word;
   int len;
   struct Entry *next;
} Entry;

#define TABLE_SIZE 1000 // random numbers for testing

Entry *table[TABLE_SIZE] = { NULL }; // an array of elements

void init() {
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++) {
      // initialize values
      struct Entry *en = (struct Entry *)malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));

      en->word = "";
      en->len = 0;
      en->next = table[i];
      table[i] = en;
   }
}

//Insert element
void insertElement(char *word, int len) {
   int h = hash(word);
   int i;

   // because all words are different so there is no need to check for duplicates
   struct Entry *en = (struct Entry *)malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));

   en->word = word;
   en->len = len;
   en->next = table[h];
   table[h] = en;
}

void cleanTable()
{
   struct Entry *p, *q;
   int i;

   for( i=0; i<TABLE_SIZE; ++i )
   {
      for( p=table[i]; p!=NULL; p=q )
      {
         q = p->next;
         free( p );
      }
   }  // for each entry
}

int main() {
   init(); // create hash table

   // test calls produce correct output
   //insertElement("A", (int)strlen("A"));
   //insertElement("A's", (int)strlen("A's"));
   //insertElement("AA's", (int)strlen("AA's"));
   //insertElement("AB's", (int)strlen("AB's"));

   int i;
   i = 0;

   FILE* dict = fopen("/usr/share/dict/words", "r"); //open the dictionary for read-only access 
   if(dict == NULL) {   
      return;                    
   }

   // Read each line of the file, and insert the word in hash table
   char word[128];      
   while(i < 4 && fgets(word, sizeof(word), dict) != NULL) {
      size_t len = strlen(word); 
      if (len > 0 &&  word[len - 1] == '\n') {
         word[len - 1] = '\0'; // trim the \n
      }

      insertElement(word, (int)strlen(word));

      i++;
   }

   for ( i=0; i < 50; i++)
   {
      printf("%d: ", i);

      struct Entry *enTemp = table[i];

      while (enTemp->next != NULL)
      {
         printf("[W: %s, Len:%d] ", enTemp->word, enTemp->len);
         enTemp = enTemp->next;
      }

      printf("\n");
   }

   cleanTable();

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reallocate the memory in each loop in this part of code:

```
char* word = malloc(sizeof(char)*128);      
while(i < 4 && fgets(word, sizeof(word), dict) != NULL) {
    size_t len = strlen(word); 
    if (len > 0 &&  word[len - 1] == '\n') {
        word[len - 1] = '\0'; // trim the \n
    }
    insertElement(word, (int)strlen(word));
    word = malloc(sizeof(char)*128);
    i++;
}
```

You forgot to reallocate memory to every string which causes all pointers points at same point

**Note: Not tested**

Answer (score 2):

notice that your **insertElement** get a pointer to a string, and assign that pointer to the current **Entry**, but its the main function, you pass the **word** argument(a pointer) that point the stack allocated string, and that string is changed after each read of a word. you must use **malloc** so that each **word** point to its own memory area